# How to identify which wire is associated with switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have two ceiling boxes in my kitchen, when I moved in one was already hooked up to a light and a switch. When I opened up the second box I saw 4 cables in the box, all of which passed though box without any cuts or terminations.
- 2x white (long)
- 2x black (long)
- 1x red   (taught)

I want to install a light in the 2nd ceiling box and have it run by the same switch as the first box. I tried using a non-contact voltage tester with switch on and off and both black wires indicated voltage regardless of switch state. Is it safe to assume that this means neither of those wires are attached to the switch?

Thanks

Comment: Many people confuse "cables" and "wires". We would need to see a picture of the interior of the box, particularly where the wires/cabes enter.   It may not be possible to distinguish the correct wires without special tricks.  It is vital not to use the wrong wires.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question?

Comment: PLEASE do not go "oh, those guys weren't helpful" and then pick random wires and "try stuff until it works".  Several combinations will "seem to work" and actually create a dangerous situation.  It's easily to do it right, we just need some snaps.